# Se puede DELETE, INPUT Y UPDATE En un solo archivo?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Estoy en el desarrollo de un proyecto con php donde el administrador puede modificar, eliminar y subir datos, pero mi duda es... Puedo hacer en un solo archivo los 3? O necesariamente tienen que ser por separado, digo para evitar tantos archivos... por que tengo mas de 10 tablas.

Comment: Respuesta, si, se puede. El asunto ya es saber cómo tienes tú código ordenado para buscar una forma o solución a tu problema. Lo suyo suele ser hacer métodos de action y según el verbo llamar al método correspondiente. Te sugiero que empieces a revisar MVC, o algún framework (symfony, Laravel...) Y ver cómo funcionan.

Comment: Okey, muchísimas gracias, voy a investigar un poco sobre los temas!